# need to convert vbscript to javascript

Tags: javascript, printing, vbscript

i need to convert this vbscript code to javascript , i am using this not to display print dialogbox and to print using default printer, it is working properly in IE and i want to make it run in Fire fox and other browsers.

VBscript Code:

```
 sub Print()
        OLECMDID_PRINT = 6
        OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER = 2
        OLECMDEXECOPT_PROMPTUSER = 1
        call WB.ExecWB(OLECMDID_PRINT, OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER,1)
    End Sub
    document.write "<object id='WB' width='0' height='0' classid='CLSID:8856F961-340A-    11D0-A96B-00C04FD705A2'></object>"
```

Comment: You won't get it to work, because only Internet Explorer supports ActiveX. I guess that that's the reason that this piece of code was written in VBscript, in the first place...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just use

```
window.print();
```

If you can print without user interaction, this is a security bug and needs to be fixed ASAP.